# How can I show that $(A-B)-(B-C)=(A-B)$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

[image]

I'm doing problems out of my book and came to this one. What I've tried is below. I just can't seem to get rid of the C on the LHS to match the RHS.

$(A\cap B^c)-(B\cap C^c)=(A\cap B^c)$

$(A\cap B^c)\cap(B\cap C^c)^c$

$(A\cap B^c)\cap(B^c\cup C)$

$A\cap [B^c\cap(B^c\cup C)]$

$A\cap [(B^c\cap B^c) \cup (B^c \cap C)]$

$A\cap [B^c \cup (B^c\cap C)]$

And am getting stuck at that point. I just don't see how to handle the C.

Comment: How do you justify this step: $\;A\cap [B^c\cap(B^c\cup C)]\;$?

Comment: I got it from the distributive law treating the whole $(b^c\cup C)$ as one thing.

Comment: Sorry, I misread that. Your proof is basically done if you write it as $(A \cap B^c) \cup (A \cap B^c \cap C)$ after the last step. Then note that $A \cap B^c \cap C \subseteq A \cap B^c$ so the union reduces to the first term.

Comment: In logic there is an Absorption law that says $A \lor (A \land B) = A$, so the counterpart for sets would be $A \cup (A \cap B) = A$. With that you can do the last step.

Comment: Just checked: for sets this is called Absorption as well. So that's what you need. Hopefully it is on the list of laws provided to you .. If not, then you will be in trouble, since Absorption cannot be derived from the other standard ones.

Comment: Yea it is. That all makes sense. I think I just got too focused on the B, C, side of it. Thank you very much.

Comment: Sorry all, why downvote?

Comment: Yea... I really wish people would explain their downvotes all the time. I mean if there's something wrong with it then it won't do any good if the person who made it doesn't know what they did wrong to avoid doing the same in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Last step will be:

$A \cap [B^C \cup (B^C \cap C)]=$ (Absorption)

$A \cap B^C$

Answer (score 1):

We have $B \setminus C \subseteq B$, hence $(A \setminus B) \cap (B \setminus C) \subseteq A\setminus B \cap B = \emptyset$. Hence $(A \setminus B) \setminus (B \setminus C) = A \setminus B$.

Comment: We haven't used the \ at all, what is it mean in these?

Comment: It means set subtraction.

Comment: Ok. That I get but I was told for this chapter we were just using the set identities laws, and not any of the subset stuff like that, so I've been trying all day to figure out how to do this one with just those.

Answer (score 0):

It is clear that
$$
(A-B)-(B-C)\subseteq A-B
$$
Suppose $x\in (A-B)$. If $x\notin (A-B)-(B-C)$, then $x\in (B-C)$, so $x\in B$. Contradiction. Therefore $x\in(A-B)-(B-C)$.